# ASync Proble on the Mysql using C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have fixing it and search many websites to have an answer but failed.
If you ca help me fixing it or what is the reason why this code won't work?
I am new to this async process. maybe some good guys here can help me or simplify my code.

Can you fix this, it won't run when it search it. something is wrong with it.

```
public async Task SearchRecord()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    _route.Enabled = false;
                    _delete.Enabled = false;
                });
                conn.Close();
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                //For load only
```

When I run this on Localhost it works fine. but the code below wont work.

```
                cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT record_tbl.ctrl_num as ctrl_num, record_tbl.sender as sender, record_tbl.subject as subject,record_tbl.serial as serial,record_tbl.Doctype as Doctype, record_tbl.dateofletter as dateofletter, record_tbl.dateofentry as dateofentry, status_tbl.status as status  from record_tbl, status_tbl where (sender LIKE '%@Search%' or subject LIKE '%@Search%' or serial LIKE '%@Search%' or Doctype LIKE '%@Search%') AND (record_tbl.ctrl_num = status_tbl.ctrl_num AND status_tbl.status = 'DRAFT' and record_tbl.receiver = '" + Properties.Settings.Default.Name + "')", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", _search.Text);
                readinfo = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                while (readinfo.Read())
                {
                    if (readinfo.HasRows)
                    {
                        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            //_edit.Enabled = true;
                            _route.Enabled = true;
                            _delete.Enabled = true;

                            Data.Add(new AccountData()
                            {
                                Control = readinfo.GetInt32("ctrl_num"),
                                Sender = readinfo.GetString("sender"),
                                Subject = readinfo.GetString("subject"),
                                Serial = readinfo.GetString("serial"),
                                Category = readinfo.GetString("doctype"),
                                Dateofletter = readinfo.GetDateTime("dateofletter").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")),
                                Dateofentry = readinfo.GetDateTime("dateofentry").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")),
                                Status = readinfo.GetString("status")
                            });

                        });

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                }


                conn.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception s)

            {

                MessageBox.Show(s.Message);
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    Error.Visible = true;
                    _route.Enabled = false;
                    _delete.Enabled = false;
                });
                conn.Close();
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Comment: Note that starting a line in your question with `>` is markdown for quote (someone else said it, it's an error message you received, it's a verbatim copy from documentation, etc.). I've removed these from your question since quoting yourself is odd.

Comment: "wont work" is way too vague. Do you get an error message? Which?

Comment: i am not really fluent on English. my apologies. :(

Comment: `When I run this on Localhost it works fine.` it doesn't work fine at all. You're starting a task only to immediatelly go back to the UI thread with `Invoke`. Even after that, you're using that task to await another task. No example or tutorial is that complicated, which should be a sign that something is wrong

Comment: For starters, *remove* `Task.Run` completely. `await `conn.OpenAsync()` is already awaiting for the remote task to complete without blocking. Once you remove `Task.Run` you no longer need `Invoke`. Use a `using` block for the connection instead of manually closing it. `using` will close the connection even in cases where `finally` won't be called

Comment: i am really sorry. i am just new to async.

Comment: Also `if (readinfo.HasRows)` and `while(readInfo.Read())` are reversed. If `Read()` returns true, so will `HasRows`. `HasRows` is used to avoid looping if there are no results.

Comment: If you're new to something, the best option is to read the tutorials and docs. This code contains plain ADO.NET errors too, like the incorrect use of the connection. And that initial ` conn.Close();` smells of a global connection, a VERY big problem that can lead to blocking, delays and deadlocks. Connections are meant to be short-lived

Comment: And an even worse problem - concatenating strings to create a SQL query. That leaves you wide open to SQL injection attacks or simple conversion problems. What if someone stored `O'Reilly` as the default receiver setting? Kaboom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to write this code is :

```
public async Task SearchRecord()
{
    _route.Enabled = false;
    _delete.Enabled = false;
    var sql=@"SELECT record_tbl.ctrl_num as ctrl_num, record_tbl.sender as sender, record_tbl.subject as subject,record_tbl.serial as serial,record_tbl.Doctype as Doctype, record_tbl.dateofletter as dateofletter, record_tbl.dateofentry as dateofentry, status_tbl.status as status  
 from record_tbl, status_tbl 
 where (sender LIKE '%@Search%' or subject LIKE '%@Search%' or serial LIKE '%@Search%' or Doctype LIKE '%@Search%') 
       AND (record_tbl.ctrl_num = status_tbl.ctrl_num 
            AND status_tbl.status = 'DRAFT' 
            and record_tbl.receiver = @receiver)";

    try
    {
        using(var conn=new MySqlConnection(...))
        using(var cmd=new MySqlCommand(sql,conn);
        {
                
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", _search.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receiver", Properties.Settings.Default.Name);
        
            //Open the connection only when needed
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            using(var readinfo = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (readinfo.Read())
                {
                    Data.Add(new AccountData(){...});
                }

                _route.Enabled = true;
                _delete.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        //Log the error before showing it, just in case
        LogTheError(exc.ToString());

        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        Error.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Using a library like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) this can be simplified to :

```
public async Task SearchRecord()
{
    _route.Enabled = false;
    _delete.Enabled = false;
    var sql=@"SELECT ...";

    try
    {
        using(var conn=new MySqlConnection(...))
        {
            IEnumerable<AccountData> results=await QueryAsync<AccountData>(sql, 
                  _search.Text, 
                  Properties.Settings.Default.Name);
        
            Data.AddRange(results);
                
            _route.Enabled = true;
            _delete.Enabled = true;
        }    
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        //Log the error before showing it, just in case
        LogTheError(exc.ToString());

        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        Error.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

There's no need for `Task.Run` to run and await asynchronous operations. Asynchronous operations already run either on another thread, or using no thread at all. I/O in Windows is always asynchronous and performed by the OS. This includes writing to disk or talking to a database over the network.

`await` doesn't *start* an asynchronous operation, it awaits an already executing one without blocking the calling thread. After `await` completes, execution is returned to the original thread. In the case of desktop applications, that's the UI thread.

`Invoke()` returns execution to the UI thread. It's not needed when `await` is used though, as execution is already back in the UI thread.

Connections are meant to be short-lived, because an open connection accumulates locks and takes up resources on the server side. Keeping a connection open for long will block other connections resulting in bad performance with even a dozen concurrent clients.

It could even lead to deadlocks if two clients end up waiting for the other to release their locked rows. If for example, two applications read an entire table and then try to write to it, they'll probably deadlock because each has already taken shared locks on all the table's rows.

There's no reason to use global connections. ADO.NET uses connection pooling to make opening and closing connections as cheap as possible. When a connection is closed, it's not deleted. Instead, ADO.NET resets it and puts it back to a pool of reusable connections. This way, opening a new connection is instantaneous.